# How to bring down maximum response time django?

Tags: django, load-testing, newrelic

I am using new relic to get some info on how long response times are taking. I have also been doing load tests using blitz. I can see on new relic that for a lot of the api endpoints it is taking around 300 ms average (which I am totally happy with these are geo spatial queries btw). The only issue is the maximum is 55k ms and some users are complaining of certain things taking a while to load.

How can I make these endpoints more reliable that they will take 300 ms more often than 55k ms?

edit:
The main question is why do these responses sometimes take 55k ms? Is this user connection speed or the code?

Comment: Kinda *how do I make my code faster*?  Without any indication of what the code is up to, besides the geo spatial aside.

Comment: I'm just wondering why it takes 55k ms sometimes and the rest of the time its around 300 ms